# Angular soundmanager stops current playing when I add new song to the playlist

Tags: angularjs, soundmanager2

Hey folks need some help over here. I am using songmanager2 to play songs and making playlist. Its working fine on Desktop browsers, but problem occurs in mobile browser, when I add songs to the playlist the current songs stops playing. I am using exactly same with the example given in github
https://github.com/perminder-klair/angular-soundmanager2

```js
app.factory('myService', function($http) {
      //var http="http://neischool.org/aamin_apps/index.php/index.php?";
      //var http="http://localhost/angulardemo/music/api/txt.json?";
      var http="http://192.168.43.108/angulardemo/music/api/txt.json?";
      var myService = {
        async: function(key,p) {
          if(p==0){
               var promise = $http.get(http+'q='+key).then(function (response) {
              return response.data;
            });
          }else{
               var promise = $http.get(http+'q='+key+'&p='+p).then(function (response) {
              return response.data;
            });
          }
         
          return promise;
        }
      };
      return myService;
    });

 app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope,myService) {
    $scope.items = [];  
    $scope.img="NO";
    $scope.page=0;
      $scope.search=function(){
        $scope.img="loading";
        var key=$scope.trackName;
        
        myService.async(key,0).then(function(d) {
            if(d==='null'){
              $("#alrt").show();
               $scope.img="NO";
               $scope.searchResult='No Song Found with the name '+key;
               $scope.page=0;
               $scope.items=[];
            }else{
              $("#alrt").hide();
               $scope.items = d;
               $scope.searchResult='';
               $scope.img="NO";
               if(d[0]['page']=='1'){
                  $scope.page=0;
               }else{
                  $scope.page=d[0]['page']; 
               }
               
               $scope.key=key;
            }
        });
      }
       $scope.searchUpdate=function(q,p){
        $scope.img="loading";
        myService.async(q,p).then(function(d) {
            $scope.items = d;
            $scope.img="NO";
            $scope.page=d[0]['page'];
            //alert(d[0]['page']);
        });
      }
       $scope.range = function(){
        var input = [];
        for (var i=1; i<=$scope.page; i++) input.push(i);
        return input;
      };

    $scope.showDetail = function(name,Bitrate,Size,link,Time) {
      $scope.trackN=name;
      localStorage.setItem("music_track_name", name);
      localStorage.setItem("music_track_bitrate", Bitrate);
      localStorage.setItem("music_track_size", Size);
      localStorage.setItem("music_track_link", link);
      localStorage.setItem("music_track_time", Time);
      
      $scope.link=link;
       var player=document.getElementById('player2');
      var sourceMp3=document.getElementById('player2');
      
      //alert(localStorage.getItem("music_track_link"));
      sourceMp3.src=localStorage.getItem("music_track_link");
      
       player.load(); 
       player.play(); 
      
    };
  });
```

```html
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
<div class="app-search" style="margin-top:-20px;background-color:#FFFFFF">
 <form class="navbar-form" role="search" ng-submit="search()">
   <div class="input-group">
    <input id="cus" ng-model="trackName" type="text" placeholder="Search Anything!" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" style="border: solid 1px #007AFF;background-color: aliceblue;">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
     <button id="cus" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>

   </div>
  <div ng-switch on="img" style="text-align:center">
            <div ng-switch-when="loading">
                <img src="img/ajax-loader.gif">
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-default>
                <!-- code to render the regular video block -->
            </div>
        </div>  
 </form>
</div>

<div class="scrollable" style="background-color:#FFFFFF">

  <div class="scrollable-content">
    <div class="list-group">
    <!-- ng-click="showDetail(x.name,x.Bitrate,x.Size,x.link,x.Time)" -->
      <button ng-repeat="x in items" ng-show="!$first" href="#" class="list-group-item" >
        <table>
         <tr>
          <!-- <td class="play_link" music-player="play" add-song="x" style="width:60px"><img class="play_link" src="img/itunes2.png" style="width:50px"></td> -->
          <td style="text-align:left;width: 100%;">
            <b>{{ x.title | limitTo:60}}</b>
            <span style="color: forestgreen;font-size:small">
             Bitrate: {{x.Bitrate}} Size: {{x.Size}} Duration: {{x.Time}}
            </span>
           </td>
           <td>
            <span class="btn btn-info pull-right" music-player="play" add-song="x"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span>
           </td>
           <td>
            <span style="margin-left:1px" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" music-player add-song="x"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
           </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
     </button>

      <div style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:15px">
      <div id="alrt" class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none;text-align:center;font-weight:bold">{{searchResult}}</div>
        <span ng-repeat="n in range()">
               <button style="border-radius:30px" id="but_{{n}}" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="searchUpdate(key,n)" class="notification">{{n}}</button>
            </span>
            <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
            <div/>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

*